# Need form to display checkbox, radiobutton group, or listbox based on task type

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've been trying to whip up a simple MS-Access task-tracking application for personal use.  My basic data model is a task-definition table (in which I can  define daily tasks) and a task-result table (in which I can track which tasks I've performed on a given day).

I'm trying to build a form which
1)  lists all daily tasks (sorted by time-of-day, an attribute of each task), and
2) next to each task, displays a widget that lets me mark the task as complete.

Here's the rub, though.  I have three (and may add more) different types of tasks:

- simple yes/no tasks (for which a single checkbox widget would work)
- score-able tasks that allow me to track how well the task was done (for which a radio-button group would fit), and
- "complex" tasks comprised of several yes/no sub-tasks (for which a multi-selection list-box would fit).

I've gotten as far as building the form so it lists all tasks in desired order, but I am 100% stuck on how to code the (conditional) data-entry widget.  Though I've had no difficulty in implementing each widget individually, my best effort is a task list with just check-boxes, just radio group, or just list boxes.  I have no idea how to tell the form to "look at" the type of each task and present the appropriate widget beside it.

I'm almost ready to throw in the towel and just hard-code all the tasks into the form, in a fixed order, along with their appropriate widget.  Is there a way to implement this in a more elegant manner?

[an aside] I chose MS-Access somewhat arbitrarily, and am learning MS-Access forms as I go.  If anyone feels I'm stuck by virtue of choosing the wrong tool for the job, feel free to let me know

Comment: You will need VBA to do this. Add all three controls to the same row (will probably end up on top of each other). Set all of their properties to "visible = no". You then write VBA code to determine which controls should be visible for each row. How to do that depends a little more on your structure. Are you using a continuous form to display open tasks, or a subform? I'm not sure this is possible without using a continuous form, but I am often wrong. Add an explanation of the structure of your form and I'm sure we can help get it working.

Comment: Related, but insufficient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669839/make-fields-visible-in-ms-access-form-as-certain-fields-are-completed

Comment: I am using a subform (parent=date, child=tasks-for-that-date), but the pertinent piece (list of tasks) is a continuous form within the subform.  My background in database design/modeling, so I won't beat myself up too much for not thinking of the "visible=no" angle.  But as soon as I read that, I realized I was asking the wrong question: it's not "how to tell Forms what to show" but "how to tell Forms what not to show".  I've got a little VBA under my belt; I'll try a few things out tonight and update if/when I get it working.

Comment: Unless there's some trick you know of, it seems this is not possible.  The desired behavior (conditionally setting appearance of controls in a continuous form based on each record's value) can only be handled through the "conditional formatting" feature - which is relegated to text & combo boxes.  There are fancy ways to play with background/foreground colors there - but there's no such feature for checkboxes/radio buttons.  Best I can do is use only checkboxes and conditional display "Pick Just One" when I wish it were a radio button.

Comment: It seems you are right. If this doesn't hinder your workflow, you could replace your control family with a single command button which launches a pop-up form with the appropriate controls on it. That's the only other idea I have. If you were only replacing command buttons I would suggest textboxes/hyperlinks to emulate functionality, you could try to get those to emulate your other controls too (textboxes can be conditionally formatted and have an OnClick event). Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's an easy way to do this.

Comment: I'm going to post an "outside the box" idea as a proposed answer - would appreciate your feedback on whether it's too crazy to be worth trying...

Answer (score 2):

As resolved in the comments to original question, it seems the main obstacle is the limitations of continuous forms.  Because Access treats each column of continuous forms as an atomic element, there are very few options available to differentiate their presentation. The only tool that comes close is Conditional Formatting, and the closest approach to selectively hiding/showing fields is to hide text-box fields using text colors that "camouflage" them into the background color.

This limitation leads to my potential work-around.

To recap the objective: Within a given day, I want to list a [table-driven] set of tasks.  Each task has options of "Yes/No", "Choose one of N choices", or "Choose 0 to N of N choices".  Depending on the type of task, it should be rendered (respectively) as a single checkbox (yes/no), a radio button group (choose one), or an checkbox group (choose many).

(An aside: I realize, as I type this, that the first type is really a subclass of the third type, but that doesn't really make the core issue go away)

The proposed idea:

At the time the form is launched, a query can be run which will tell exactly which task will fall into exactly which position.  In other words, before "drawing" today's tasks, the database can answer which task will be in position 1, which will be in position 2, and so on.  Additionally, I can safely say that there will never be more than, say, 20 tasks (though the actual number of task on any given day can vary).

Which leads me to wonder: what if I designed the form with 20 "slots", and in each slot, had 3 overlaying presentations: one for Yes/No tasks, one for a "Choose one" tasks, and one for "Choose many" tasks. (60 total - sounds horrific, but I'd hope copy/paste would come to the rescue).

When Access renders the form, each slot would query for the "nth" task of the day (so the 1st slot would query for the first task, the 2nd slot for the second task, and so on).  The "visible" option would then be set to "Yes" for only the presentation that matched the type of task returned by the query.  So if the 3rd slot, querying for the 3rd task, received a task of the "yes/no" variety, only the "yes/no" prompt would be displayed.

For what it's worth, I do have a working version of my application already (though checking & unchecking check-boxes according to whether a task is labeled as "pick one" or "pick many" definitely grates on me).  So if there's a reason to think this new approach won't work, I'd be happy to hear it before I throw any real development time at it.

Comment: This should work. Of course it will be an unbound form, so every loading and saving of data must be coded. -- You can use [CreateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836740.aspx) with the form open in Design view to create all those controls. Be sure to name them e.g. `optGrp1` .. `optGrp20`, so you can loop the controls. I strongly recommend using this, so if you find out you want a different layout (e.g. 4x5 instead of 5x4) or more controls, you can just change some constants and let it run again.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for the tip; CreateControl sounds much more enticing than manually drawing in the 20x3 possible controls.  This is a "spare-time" project, so likely to be drawn out for many more days, but I'll update/accept answer if it works out